# How to convert genomic SNPs to a binary format?

Tags: python, r, awk, bioinformatics

I am struggling to figure out how to convert a (SNP) file looking like this:

```
pos,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample7,sample8,sample9,sample10,sample11,sample12,sample13,sample14
79107,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,G,G
79115,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,A,C,C,T,C,C,C
79116,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
79124,C,C,T,T,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
79128,G,G,G,G,A,G,G,G,G,C,G,G,G,G
```

To a binary format like this:

```
pos,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample7,sample8,sample9,sample10,sample11,sample12,sample13,sample14
79107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
79115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
79116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
79124,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
79128,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

Does anyone know a package in R, or command line tool, awk code, that can be used for this?

A problem with the solutions below is that all do this:

```
1097023,A,A,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,A,A
1097027,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
4363243,C,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A 
4363270,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T 
4363275,A,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G
```

```
1097023,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
1097027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363243,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
4363275,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

While it should be:

```
1097023,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
1097027,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363243,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 
4363275,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

So I think the solution should include that if the majority of samples 'i.e. > 7 samples' is the same, this becomes a 0, the ones that don't match the majority become 1.

Comment: What's the logic here? `C` becomes `0` in the second-last line, and `1` in the last line. We'd need more information about the target format you want.

Comment: DNA consists of either A,C,T or G, so these are the 4 options you can have. Normally you will see the same in each of the samples so all A, all C, all T or all G. 
However, if you have a "mutation = conversion from e.g. C to G", this is called a SNP. 
For downstream analysis I need to have a binary format where everything is 0, except the places where one or more of the samples don't match with the rest for a given position (first column "pos").

Comment: All we have to go on is the information you provide in your question. When the answers were posted there was nothing in your question to suggest what you've now added that `I think the solution should include that if the majority of samples 'i.e. > 7 samples' is the same, this becomes a 0, the ones that don't match the majority become 1.`. You might want to put this question back as it was, accept an answer to the question you asked, and then ask a followup with your new requirements and a more truly representative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple `awk` (standard Linux `awk/gawk`) script:

#### script.awk

```
BEGIN {FS = ","} # set field seperator to ","
NR>1{     # every line except the first line
  zeroIndc=$2; # identify the zero indicator and save the variable
  for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { # for each DNA letter
    if ($i == zeroIndc) { # if DNA letter match zero indicator
      $i = 0; # set DNA letter to 0
    } else { # if DNA letter not match zero indicator
      $i = 1; # set DNA letter to 1
    }
  }
  print; # print new line at end 
}
```

#### run script `script.awk`

```
awk -f scirpt.awk input.txt
```

#### run single liner awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR>1{z=$2;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)$i=($i==z)?0:1;print;}' input.txt
```

Comment: This is perfect, I tried it on a large dataset and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll have to set `OFS=","` too or it'll replace every comma with a blank.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can compare every `sample` column with the first sample column and turn return 1 where the values don't match.

```
cols <- grep('sample', names(df))
df[cols] <- +(df$sample1 != df[cols])
df

#    pos sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 sample7 sample8 sample9
#1 79107       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#2 79115       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0
#3 79116       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
#4 79124       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0       0
#5 79128       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0

#  sample10 sample11 sample12 sample13 sample14
#1        0        0        0        1        1
#2        0        1        0        0        0
#3        0        0        0        0        0
#4        0        0        0        0        0
#5        1        0        0        0        0
```

---

Although the above one is going to be more efficient on large datasets but here is an alternative with `dplyr` library.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(contains('sample'), ~+(sample1 != .)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(pos = c(79107L, 79115L, 79116L, 79124L, 79128L
), sample1 = c("C", "C", "A", "C", "G"), sample2 = c("C", "C", 
"A", "C", "G"), sample3 = c("C", "C", "A", "T", "G"), sample4 = c("C", 
"C", "A", "T", "G"), sample5 = c("C", "C", "A", "C", "A"), sample6 = c("C", 
"C", "A", "C", "G"), sample7 = c("C", "C", "A", "C", "G"), sample8 = c("C", 
"A", "A", "C", "G"), sample9 = c("C", "C", "A", "C", "G"), sample10 = c("C", 
"C", "A", "C", "C"), sample11 = c("C", "T", "A", "C", "G"), sample12 = c("C", 
"C", "A", "C", "G"), sample13 = c("G", "C", "A", "C", "G"), sample14 = c("G", 
"C", "A", "C", "G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I tried both of your solotions. They're useful however I have the same issue as with the awk solutions that were posted: 


`4363243,C,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
4363270,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T
4363275,A,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G
`

becomes

`4363243,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363275,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
`
Instead of

`4363243,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363275,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
`

I can of course manually remove those but I am wondering if there is a way to fix this

Comment: @XelaVi Sorry, it is not clear what you want to show from the comment as the code is not formatted correctly. You can update your post to include any additional details.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{gsub($2,0); gsub(/[ACTG]/,1)} 1' file
pos,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample7,sample8,sample9,sample10,sample11,sample12,sample13,sample14
79107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
79115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0
79116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
79124,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
79128,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: The only problem with this and the other awk solution is that:

`4363243,C,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
4363270,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T
4363275,A,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G,G
`

becomes

`4363243,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363275,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
`
Instead of

`4363243,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363270,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4363275,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
`

But I can manually remove those cases ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to code as `0` the "reference" allele, where "reference" is simply the most common, here is a solution using Python 3, its `pandas` data processing library (to be installed using `pip3 install pandas`) and the [`Counter` specialized dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Starting with a file `snps_letters.csv` containing your example data:

```
$ cat snps_letters.csv
pos,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample7,sample8,sample9,sample10,sample11,sample12,sample13,sample14
79107,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,G,G
79115,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,A,C,C,T,C,C,C
79116,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
79124,C,C,T,T,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
79128,G,G,G,G,A,G,G,G,G,C,G,G,G,G
```

We will open it, transform it and save it in the script `binarize.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# Load the comma-separated data in a pandas DataFrame object:
snps = pd.read_csv("snps_letters.csv", index_col="pos")

def binarize(column):
    # Extracting the most common element as ref
    # (using list and tuple unpacking,
    # because the most_common method returns
    # a list of (element, count) pairs):
    [(ref, _)] = Counter(column).most_common(1)
    # We can now define an auxiliary function
    # to recode individual elements in the column:
    def to_bin(elem):
        # int(True) -> 1, int(False) -> 0
        return 1 - int(elem == ref)
    # Transform the column by applying the recoding function to its elements
    # (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply):
    return column.apply(to_bin)

# Now apply our column-transforming function to the columns (axis=0)
# (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):
binarized = snps.apply(binarize, axis=0)
# Write the result to a file:
binarized.to_csv("snps_binary.csv")
```

Executing the script in the shell:

```
$ ./binarize.py
```

Checking the saved results:

```
$ cat snps_binary.csv 
pos,sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6,sample7,sample8,sample9,sample10,sample11,sample12,sample13,sample14
79107,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
79115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1
79116,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
79124,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
79128,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0
```

To have a more re-usable script, you could pass the input and output file paths as arguments to the command line, and they would be accessible in the python code as `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` (provided you `import sys` first).

---

A version that takes input and output files on the command-line, and codes the reference nucleotide as 1 instead of 0:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# Load the comma-separated data in a pandas DataFrame object:
snps = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1], index_col="pos")

def binarize(column):
    # Extracting the most common element as ref
    # (using list and tuple unpacking,
    # because the most_common method returns
    # a list of (element, count) pairs):
    [(ref, _)] = Counter(column).most_common(1)
    # We can now define an auxiliary function
    # to recode individual elements in the column:
    def to_bin(elem):
        # int(True) -> 1, int(False) -> 0
        return int(elem == ref)
    # Transform the column by applying the recoding function to its elements
    # (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply):
    return column.apply(to_bin)

# Now apply our column-transforming function to the columns (axis=0)
# (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):
binarized = snps.apply(binarize, axis=0)
# Write the result to a file:
binarized.to_csv(sys.argv[2])
```

It would be used as follows:

```
./binarize.py snps_letters.csv snps_binary.csv
```

Comment: Hey, I tried running your script and I get the same results as you but this is not correct all the way. 79128,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0 should have 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1

Comment: This happens throughout my whole dataset. I tried setting most_common(0), but it didn't help.

Comment: @XelaVi If you want the most common to be coded as 1 instead of 0, change `return 1 - int(elem == ref)` to `return int(elem == ref)`. The `1` in the `most_common` method of `Counter` specifies that we want only the most common element. If we put `2`, it means we want the 2 most common. I don't know what happens if we put 0...

Comment: @XelaVi I added a new version at the end that does the inverse coding. But I think there may still be differences with what you expect. The existence of ex-aequo in the most common for some samples makes the choice somewhat arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Identify reference allele, in this case, reference based on most frequent allele, using [data from Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64206722/680068), we have 5 SNPs REF alleles:

```r
REF <- apply(df[, -1], 1, function(i) names(which.max(table(i)))) 
# [1] "C" "C" "A" "C" "G"
```

Now, compare columnwise, per sample, to *REF*, then convert to integer by multiplying logical TRUE/FALSE with 1. And assign it back to the original *dataframe*:

```r
df[, -1] <- (df[, -1] != REF) * 1
df
#     pos sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6 sample7 sample8 sample9 sample10 sample11 sample12 sample13 sample14
# 1 79107       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0        0        1        1
# 2 79115       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       1       0        0        1        0        0        0
# 3 79116       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0        0        0        0        0        0
# 4 79124       0       0       1       1       0       0       0       0       0        0        0        0        0        0
# 5 79128       0       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0        1        0        0        0        0
```